# How to check if startTime and startDate is less than endTime and endDate?

Tags: android, validation, android-calendar, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

I'm developing an app in which I want to check if `startTime` and `startDate` is less than `endTime` and `endDate` and if it is then only the information should be saved in `FirebaseDatabase`.

I'm using this code to check is `startTime` < `endTime` and `startDate` < `endDate`:

```
        try {
            Date date1 = currentTime.parse(btnChooseStartTime.getText().toString());
            Date date2 = currentTime.parse(btnChooseEndTime.getText().toString());
            differenceBetweenStartEndTime = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

            isEndDateGreaterThanStartDate = CheckDates(btnChooseEndDate.getText().toString(), btnChooseStartDate.getText().toString());

            if (String.valueOf(differenceBetweenStartEndTime).contains("-")) {
               Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                  .make(coordinatorLayout, "Start time is greater than end time. Fix it please.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
               snackbar.setDuration(3500);
               snackbar.show();
               progressDialogPostingE.dismiss();
            } else if (!isEndDateGreaterThanStartDate) {
               Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                  .make(coordinatorLayout, "Start date is greater than end date. Fix it please.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
               snackbar.setDuration(3500);
               snackbar.show();
               progressDialogPostingE.dismiss();
            } else {
// code for storing information in database
}
```

here's `CheckDates()` method:

```
public static boolean CheckDates(String d2, String d1)    {
        SimpleDateFormat dfDate  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        boolean b = false;
        try {
            if(dfDate.parse(d1).before(dfDate.parse(d2)))
            {
                b = true;//If start date is before end date
            }
            else if(dfDate.parse(d1).equals(dfDate.parse(d2)))
            {
                b = true;//If two dates are equal
            }
            else if (dfDate.parse(d2).before(dfDate.parse(d1)))
            {
                b = false; //If start date is after the end date

            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return b;
    }
```

This code is working almost fine but when I'm setting startDate = `20-11-2016` and startTime = `10 AM` and then endDate = `21-11-2016` and endTime = `8 AM`, I'm getting `"Start time is greater than end time. Fix it please."` shown in the `SnackBar` because `8 AM` is less than `10 AM`, but here the 10 AM is of previous day and 8 AM is of next day. So, it should have stored the data in database instead of showing the SnackBar.

What's wrong and how to fix this?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add SimpleDateFormat with hours,minutes and seconds

```
 SimpleDateFormat dfDate  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  boolean b = false;
    try {
        if(dfDate.parse(d1).before(dfDate.parse(d2)))
        {
            b = true;//If start date is before end date
        }
        else if(dfDate.parse(d1).equals(dfDate.parse(d2)))
        {
            b = true;//If two dates are equal
        }
        else if (dfDate.parse(d2).before(dfDate.parse(d1)))
        {
            b = false; //If start date is after the end date

        }
```

Comment: do I need to change the way I'm storing date and time in database?

Comment: yes you can store like this format dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss...or you parse date before check validation